# how do we plan the outage for kafka cluster when we are using kafka for spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

If due to some reason we need to bring the kafka cluster down and still source continue to produce data then there will be loss of data, how do we plan the outage for kafka cluster.

Please advise how we can handle this scenario?

I have tried searching but could not get the answer for this.

Comment: I think your question is not clear. How do you get data if your entire kafka cluster is down?

Comment: @piyush I have corrected my question now. I think the old one was a little confusing. Can you please have a look at the question now.

Comment: jin, I think if you have entire cluster outage planned, you have to point the feed to some other cluster, not sure if that's feasible in your case. If you're planning for single broker outage, then that's possible as other brokers will distribute the messages.

Comment: Thanks, Piyush for your reply. As you suggested we can go for the green-blue deployment model but do you think that this can be used for already productionized sytem?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it can't but you need to consider the cost associated with having identical system as a standby which most organizations won't prefer. At our organization, mostly if hardware issues occur, they occur on single node and we perform maintenance tasks on that node and then get that server back online. I think most organizations would do the same.

If this answers, please cast your vote.